# Security function, intrabar iteration

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to confirm if there is a recent issue/change in the security function for fetching the intrabar data has stopped working. I was using the basic logic as shared in the pinecoder FAQ and Code page.

```
f_qtyIntrabars(_res) =>
// Returns qty of intrabars in current chart bar.
var int _initCnt = 0
_initCnt := change(time(_res)) ? 1 : _initCnt + 1
_initCnt
qtyIntrabars = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", f_qtyIntrabars("D"))
```

Is now returning 1 always. Earlier it would return 25 in my case, since a Day session is 6hrs and 15min in my case. (Indian Equity markets). Any pointers would be of great help. I tried the pinecode chat, but could not confirm the issue. Thanks.

Comment: There’s a bug in security last couple days maybe just check back later

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming @Bjorgum

Comment: yes its fixed! No worries